# Cannot resolve method 'start()' in Java implements Runnable

Tags: java

I want to run the two threads alternately to write down the alphabet. Dont know what i wrote wrong in my code, but the .start()-Method cannot be resolved by the IDE. Searched a lot but could not find an answer to my problem. I'm thankful for every Idea.

```
public class ABCThread_2 implements Runnable
{
    private boolean issmall;
    private boolean istall;

    public ABCThread_2(boolean istall, boolean issmall)
    {
        this.istall = istall;
        this.issmall = issmall;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if(issmall)
        {
            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                }

                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {

                }

                System.out.print(c);
            }
        }

        else if(istall)
        {
            for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                }

                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {

                }

                System.out.print(c);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ABCThread_2 th1 = new ABCThread_2(false, true);
        ABCThread_2 th2 = new ABCThread_2(true, false);
        th1.start();
        th2.start();


    }


}
```

Comment: Hi DeGtz.  You seem new to Java, and the confusion between Thread and Runnable is fairly common.  But you haven't done your homework.  I suggest searching on "java thread tutorial" and reading things like this (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) before resorting to stackoverflow for answers that are so easily found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runnable` doesn't have a `start` method (that `ABCThread_2` would inherit). You surely mean to call `Thread.start`. In that case, create Thread instances with your `Runnable`s:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread th1 = new Thread(new ABCThread_2(false, true));
    Thread th2 = new Thread(new ABCThread_2(true, false));
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Runnable` doesn't have a `start` method.

You're confusing `Runnable` and `Thread`s. `Thread`s accept a `Runnable`, and invoke it in a new thread.

You need to create a new `Thread` explicitly:

```
// Create your Runnable
Runnable runnable = new ABCThread_2(false, true);

// Then give it to a new instance of a Thread to run
Thread th1 = new Thread(runnable);

// And now you can start the Thread
th1.start();
```

Although your naming here confuses things. `ABCThread_2` should really be renamed to something descriptive, and something that doesn't suggest that it is itself a subclass of `Thread`.